# Extracting just the open port numbers from netstat output

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have the following output from this command:

```
netstat -ant |grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $4 }' 
0.0.0.0:111
192.168.122.1:53
0.0.0.0:22
127.0.0.1:631
127.0.0.1:25
:::111
:::22
::1:631
::1:25
```

How do extract just the last port numbers from the output?

Comment: From every line or only from last line?

Comment: The port number from each line.

Comment: With awk: append `| awk -F ":" '{print $NF}'`. `$NF` is content of last column.

Comment: Thanks.. that works too!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

append to your line

```
| sed 's/.*://'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rev` and `cut` to do this:

```
netstat -ant | awk '/LISTEN/ { print $4 }' | rev | cut -f1 -d: | rev
```

- the first `rev` reverses the output so that the last field is flipped to the front
- `cut -f1` extracts the first field
- the final `rev` reverses the string back to its original orientation

You can do it with just `awk` as well, which is more efficient:

```
netstat -ant | awk '/LISTEN/ { n = split($4, a, ":"); print a[n] }'
```

- `split` splits the string by delimiter and stores it in array and returns the size of the array
- `print a[n]` prints the last element of the array (note that array index starts with 1 in awk)

Answer (score 0):

try this with awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
netstat -ant | awk '/LISTEN/{sub(/.[^:]*/,"");gsub(/:| .*/,"");print}'
```

Above will give ports for 4th column but if you want to take output for 4th column before the status(LISTEN/TIME_WAIT) etc one then following may help you too.

```
netstat -ant | awk '/LISTEN/{split($5, a,":");print a[2]}'
```