# Looking for the best way in bash shell to extract a string

Tags: string, bash, parsing, awk, grep

I have the following string being exported from a program that is analyzing the certificate on a website which will be part of a bugfix analysis

```
CERT_SUMMARY:127.0.0.1:127.0.0.1:631:sha256WithRSAEncryption:
/O=bfcentos7-test/CN=bfcentos7-test/emailAddress=root$bfcentos7-
test:/O=bfcentos7-test/CN=bfcentos7-test/emailAddress=root$bfcentos7-
test:170902005715Z:270831005715Z:self signed certificate
```

(consider output above to be a single line)

What I need is the best way in a bash shell to extract the `sha256WithRSAEncryption`. This could be anything like `sha384withRSAEncryption` or something else.

After the `CERTSUMMARY` it will always be `127.0.0.1:127.0.0.1:portnum` above its port `631`, but it could be anything.

This runs internally on a system and returns this string along with SSL or TLS (not pictured)

Here is another example of a return

```
CERT_SUMMARY:127.0.0.1:127.0.0.1:52311:sha256WithRSAEncryption:
/CN=ServerSigningCertificate_0/name=Type`Administrator
/name=DBName`ServerSigningCertificate_0:/C=US/CN=BLAHBLAH/
ST=California/L=Address, Emeryville CA 94608/O=IBM BigFix Evaluation 
License/OU=Customer/emailAddress=blahblay@gmail.com/name=
Hash`sha1/name=Server`bigfix01/name=CustomActions`Enable
/name=LicenseAllocation`999999/name=CustomRetrievedProperties`Enable:
170702212459Z:270630212459Z:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Thanks in advance. 
Novice at shell programming, but learning!!

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? You want to know if `sha256WithRSAEncryption` or `sha384withRSAEncryption` is in the string or you want to extract values following that string? Please clarify.

Comment: Do you remember [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370872/extracting-just-the-open-port-numbers-from-netstat-output#comment79701789_46370872) posting?

Comment: Yes.. I want to extract the sha256WithRSAEncryption or whatever value is in that section of the text

Comment: `awk -F ":" '/CERT_SUMMARY/ {print $5}' file`?

Comment: @cyrus is it really as simple as picking the right column with awk?

Comment: Use `-F` to set field separator, `/.../` to grab for a string in the line and select column with `$5` (e.g.). If your string is only one line you can omit `/.../`.

Comment: Thank you... very helpful!!

Comment: Instead of posting multi-line text and then telling us to consider it as if it was on a single line, just post it as a single line.

Answer (score 2):

you need the best way and yet do not seem to provide the best description - "This could be anything like sha384withRSAEncryption or something else."
Given the examples, the string you are looking for is the 4th, when : is a separator, so the command should be OK:

```
cut -f4 -d":"
```

If the output string has a strict length format, one easy option is the 'cut' command with -c. This is not the case though since there is a port number. 
CERT_SUMMARY:127.0.0.1:127.0.0.1:631:sha256WithRSAEncryption:

Comment: Right approach but it's the 5th field, not the 4th.

Answer (score 1):

as @cyrus pointed out, this was as simple as picking the right column with awk... I am learning. 
This worked

```
awk -F ":" '/CERT_SUMMARY/ {print $5}'
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
| sed -E 's/^([^:]*:){4}([^:]*):.*/\2/'
```

Regular expressions are you friend. If there is one thing one really should be familiar with if one needs to do a lot of string parsing or string processing, it's definitely regular expressions.

```
echo 'CERT_SUMMARY:127.0.0.1:127.0.0.1:52311:sha256WithRSAEncryption:
/CN=ServerSigningCertificate_0/name=Type`Administrator
/name=DBName`ServerSigningCertificate_0:/C=US/CN=BLAHBLAH/ST=California
/L=Address, Emeryville CA 94608/O=IBM BigFix Evaluation 
License/OU=Customer/emailAddress=blahblay@gmail.com/name=Hash`sha1
/name=Server`bigfix01/name=CustomActions`Enable
/name=LicenseAllocation`999999
/name=CustomRetrievedProperties
`Enable:170702212459Z:270630212459Z:unable to get local issuer 
certificate' 
| sed -E 's/^([^:]*:){4}([^:]*):.*/\2/'
```

prints

```
sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

It's probably a bit overkill here, but there is almost nothing that cannot be done with regular expressions and as you have also built-in regex support in many languages today, knowing regex is never going to be a waste of time.

See also [here](https://regex101.com/r/JzTJDT/1) to get a nice explanation of what each regex expression actually means, including an interactive editing view. Basically I'm telling the regex parser to skip the first 4 groups consisting of any number of characters that are not `:`, followed by a single `:` and then capture the 5th group that consists of any number of characters that are not `:` and finally match anything else (no matter what) to the end of the string. The whole regex is part of a sed "replace" operation, where I replace the whole string by just the content that has been captured by the second capture group (everything in round parenthesis is a capture group).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use following also, not printing it by field's number so if your Input_file's sha256 location is a bit here and there too than shown one then this could be more helpful too.

```
awk '{match($0,/sha.*Encryption:/);if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to:

```
awk ‘BEGIN{FS=“:”} {print $5}’
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a step back to the openssl x509 command 'name options'. Using sep_comma_plus avoids the slashes in the output and therefore your regex will be simpler.